# Is it possible in HTML5 to give translation service a hint for translating a specific element

Tags: html, translation, machine-translation

I would like a specific element to be translated in a specific way for a specific language pair. For example, a movie-related web page like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
...
<p>
 <span>Kamera:</span>
 <span translate="no">XYZ</span>
</p>
```

when translated (by Google) from Turkish to English, it becomes:

```
Camera: XYZ
```

which is OK. But when translated to Greek, it becomes:

```
ΦΩΤΟΓΡΑΦΙΚΗ ΜΗΧΑΝΗ: XYZ
```

which is not correct in this context and also the letter case becomes strangely UPPERCASE.

So, I would like to be able to give a hint to the translation engine, with a code like this:

```
<p>
 <span translate="tr:el:Κάμερα">Kamera:</span>
 <span translate="no">XYZ</span>
</p>
```

I know that the HTML code above is invalid. Is there a pure HTML-type method to give such hints to translation engines? A Google-specific method might also help.

Comment: Translating is more complicated than this. You can not translate just words and that is the reason why translation engines still have so many issues. E.g. `safe and sound` cannot be translated directly. In the context of this very combination, it means being well or fine. If you want an accurate translation, then you need to translate by a real translator and serve different localized webpages for different users.

Comment: the W3C instructions on translation can be found here: https://www.w3.org/International/i18n-drafts/pages/translation.html

Comment: @tacoshy The problem in my case is that there is not enough context for the automatic translation engine to be able to find the correct meaning of that single word.

Comment: do you want to implement custom translate? of any html element

Comment: @iDibya.com  Yes. I need a custom translating for a specific element as in the example I have given.

Comment: This is a bit difficult since all browsers translate using different methods and there is no any standards, but you can do it separately for each.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any good solution to that problem, though you can try to exploit css queries to replace content, something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style>
:lang(el) span[data-translate-el-camera] span {
    display: none;
}
:lang(el) span[data-translate-el-camera]:after {
    content: "Κάμερα";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
 <span data-translate-el-camera><span>Kamera:</span></span>
 <span translate="no">XYZ</span>
</p>
</body>
```

it is not very reliable method, but it works at least in chrome

Comment: Thanks. Quite awkward, but very interesting. Is it possible to replace the style definitions in the `head` section with inline definitions in the `span` elements?

Comment: @FedKad no, as far as I remember queries can go only into style/css file

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can do it with `MutationObserver`s, this code will run if any element's `class` or `_msttexthash` attribute changes.
Chrome adds `translated-ltr` class to document when translated
and Edge adds `_msttexthash` attribute to elements when translated

```js
const attributeAddedCallback = function (mutationsList) {
    // Now this will run on any class change or _msttexthash attribute change
};
// Observe for changes on translate
const observer = new MutationObserver(attributeAddedCallback);
observer.observe(langspan, { attributes: true, subtree: true, attributeFilter: ['class', '_msttexthash'] });
```

Now we must check if page translated

```js
const attributeAddedCallback = function (mutationsList) {
    // For Chrome
    if (document.documentElement.className.match('translated-ltr')) {
        // Translated
        dotranslations();
    } else {
        // For Edge
        var translated = false;
        for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
            if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === '_msttexthash') {
                translated = true;
            }
        }
        if (translated) {
            // Translated
            dotranslations();
        }
    }
};
// Observe for changes on translate
const observer = new MutationObserver(attributeAddedCallback);
observer.observe(langspan, { attributes: true, subtree: true, attributeFilter: ['class', '_msttexthash'] });
```

Now we can detect page translated into which language with using a control text
-If "language" translated into "dil" then page translated into Turkish
-If "language" translated into "Γλώσσα" then page translated into Greek
...

```js
langs = { 'dil': 'tr', 'language': 'en', 'Γλώσσα': 'el' }; // Add as you need

var langspan = document.createElement("span");
langspan.innerText = "dil";
langspan.lang = "tr";
langspan.translate = "yes";

function dotranslations() {
    var lang = langs[langspan.innerText];
    document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(element => {
        if (element.hasAttribute('translate-suggestion-' + lang)) {
            element.innerText = element.getAttribute('translate-suggestion-' + lang);
        }
    });
}
```

Now construct the code:

translationsuggests.js

```js
langs = { 'dil': 'tr', 'language': 'en', 'Γλώσσα': 'el' };

// Language control span that hidden
var langspan = document.createElement("span");
langspan.style.position = "fixed";
langspan.style.opacity = "0";
langspan.style.pointerEvents = "none";
langspan.innerText = "dil";
langspan.lang = "tr";
langspan.translate = "yes";
document.body.appendChild(langspan);

function dotranslations() {
    var lang = langs[langspan.innerText];
    document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(element => {
        if (element.hasAttribute('translate-suggestion-' + lang)) {
            element.innerText = element.getAttribute('translate-suggestion-' + lang);
        }
    });
}

const attributeAddedCallback = function (mutationsList) {
    // For Chrome
    if (document.documentElement.className.match('translated-ltr')) {
        // Translated
        dotranslations();
    } else {
        // For Edge
        for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
            if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === '_msttexthash') {
                // Translated
                dotranslations();
            }
        }
    }
};
// Observe for changes on translate
const observer = new MutationObserver(attributeAddedCallback);
observer.observe(langspan, { attributes: true, subtree: true, attributeFilter: ['class', '_msttexthash'] });
```

Usage

```html
<html lang="tr">
<body>
    <script src="path/to/translationsuggests.js"></script>
    <p translate="yes" translate-suggestion-el="Κάμερα:" translate-suggestion-en="Cam:">Kamera:</p>
    <span translate="no">XYZ</span>
</body>
</html>
```

## EDIT

I said "Chrome adds `translated` class to document" but it was adding `translated-ltr`, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Quite complex, but interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can do it.

```js
        function customizeTranslations() {
            const kameraElement = document.getElementById('kamera');
            const xyzElement = document.getElementById('xyz');

            const customTranslations = {
            'Kamera:': 'Camera:',
            'XYZ': 'Custom Translation for XYZ'
            };
            if (kameraElement.textContent in customTranslations) {
                kameraElement.textContent = customTranslations[kameraElement.textContent];
            }
            if (xyzElement.textContent in customTranslations) {
                xyzElement.textContent = customTranslations[xyzElement.textContent];
            }
        }
```

```html
    <h1>Translation with Hints</h1>
    <p>
        <span id="kamera">Kamera:</span>
        <span id="xyz">XYZ</span>
    </p>
    <button onclick="customizeTranslations()">Customize Translations</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But, that is not something that I was looking for. The whole page is being automatically translated by Google Translate. I just want to give a hint to the machine translation towards the right direction (with no user action).

Comment: As of my knowledge, there isn't a standardized HTML attribute or method that enables you to provide hints to machine translation services, such as Google Translate, for specific elements on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Although still not exactly what in my original question I was asking about, I tried to improve the answer from @IłyaBursov as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style>
/* by default display only "tr" and nothing else: */
[class^="lang_"] {  display: none;  }
.lang_tr {  display: inline;  }

/* Now enable only the relevant language content: */
:lang(el) > .lang_el {  display: inline;  }
:lang(el) > .lang_tr {  display: none;  }

:lang(en) > .lang_en {  display: inline;  }
:lang(en) > .lang_tr {  display: none;  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
 <span class="lang_tr">Kamera</span>
 <span class="lang_el">Κάμερα</span>
 <span class="lang_en">Cam</span>
 <span translate="no">XYZ</span>
</p>
</body>
```

This way, I got rid of putting "content" inside CSS, the CSS code is "static" now, and the HTML code is more easy to understand.